# Calculating the TF-IDF of a query string over a trained set of documents

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a code that calculates the TF-IDF matrix of 150 documents.

```
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
all_lines = []
all_lines_corrected = []
with open("Extracted Functional Goals - Stemmed.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        temp = line.split(None,1)
        all_lines.append(temp[1])


f.close()
for a in range(len(all_lines)-1):
    all_lines_corrected.append(all_lines[a][:-2])

all_lines_corrected.append(all_lines[len(all_lines)-1])

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words = stop_words)
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(all_lines_corrected).todense()
query_string = raw_input("Enter string : ")
```

How do I get the TF - IDF of a query string?  ( Can we assume it looks like an entry to 150 trained documents ? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the tf-idf values of your query string by using `values = tf.transform([query_string])`. The result will be a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/sparse.html) with 1 row and N columns, where the columns are tfidf values for the N unique words that your vectorizer has seen in the training documents.

Short example, similar to your code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
all_lines = ["This is an example doc", "Another short example document .", "Just a third example"]

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word')
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(all_lines)
query_string = "This is a short example string"
print "Query String:"
print tf.transform([query_string])
print "Example doc:"
print tf.transform(["This is a short example doc"])
```

Output:

```
Query String:
  (0, 9)        0.546454011634
  (0, 7)        0.546454011634
  (0, 5)        0.546454011634
  (0, 4)        0.32274454218
Example doc:
  (0, 9)        0.479527938029
  (0, 7)        0.479527938029
  (0, 5)        0.479527938029
  (0, 4)        0.283216924987
  (0, 2)        0.479527938029
```